# Fixed field of automorphisms group of a non-Galois extension

Tags: galois-theory

If $k$ is a perfect field and $K/k$ a non-Galois extension, how can I show that the fixed field of $Aut_k(K)$ is not $k$ please ?

Comment: Theorem 14 from Emil Artin's *Galois theory*: If $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ is a group of automorphisms of a field $E$ and if $F$ is the fixed field, then $[E:F]=n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Artin's lemma, we have

$$[K : K^{Aut_k(K)}] = |Aut_k(K)| < [K:k]$$

So $k$ is not $K^{Aut_k(K)}$.